# Iterate array and sum 1 to each element

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am having some problems trying to solve a problem with arrays. Well, I have an array of integers like this and one block to add:

```
var model = [1,2,1,0,1]; var block = 1;
```

Now I have to add 1 to each element once, and I should have a result like this:

```
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,0,0,0] = [1,2,1,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [1,0,0,0,0] = [2,2,1,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,1,0,0,0] = [1,3,1,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,1,0,0] = [1,2,2,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,0,1,0] = [1,2,1,1,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,0,0,1] = [1,2,1,0,2]
```

The result should be an array of 5x5. The problem gets more complicated when I have to add  more iterations more than 1 time.

```
var model = [1,2,1,0,1]; var block = 2;
```

Now I have the same array but I have to add 2 blocks in this way:

```
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,0,0,0] + [0,0,0,0,0] = [1,2,1,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [1,0,0,0,0] + [0,0,0,0,0] = [2,2,1,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,1,0,0,0] + [0,0,0,0,0] = [1,3,1,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,1,0,0] + [0,0,0,0,0] = [1,2,2,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,0,1,0] + [0,0,0,0,0] = [1,2,1,1,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,0,0,1] + [0,0,0,0,0] = [1,2,1,0,2]

[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,0,0,0] + [1,0,0,0,0] = [2,2,1,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [1,0,0,0,0] + [1,0,0,0,0] = [3,2,1,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,1,0,0,0] + [1,0,0,0,0] = [2,3,1,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,1,0,0] + [1,0,0,0,0] = [2,2,2,0,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,0,1,0] + [1,0,0,0,0] = [2,2,1,1,1]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,0,0,1] + [1,0,0,0,0] = [2,2,1,0,2]
     .             .             .             .
     .             .             .             .
     .             .             .             .
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,0,1,0] + [0,0,0,0,1] = [1,2,1,1,2]
[1,2,1,0,1] + [0,0,0,0,1] + [0,0,0,0,1] = [1,2,1,0,4]
```

I have a function solving the first part, I can make it when I have to iterate 1 block. Like this:

```
    function iterateOneBlock(in_array){

       n_out_array = [];

       for(i=0; i<in_array.length; i++){
            tmp_array = in_array;
            tmp_array[i]++;
            n_out_array[i] = tmp_array;
       }
       return n_out_array;
    }

    const myarray = [1,2,1,0,1];
    var myarrayofarray = iterateOneBlock(myarray);

    console.log(myarrayofarray);
```

Comment: You're adding `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` as well, resulting in 6x5 array, not 5x5, though?

Comment: Adding two block actually implies generating all the possible combinations of each second block against each first block, is that right?

Comment: Also, `func` is not a legal keyword in JavaScript; `out_array` is not defined (you likely mean `n_out_array`). If you are showing code, please make sure it is [example] (emphasis on "reproducible", we shouldn't have to debug bugs that don't actually exist in your code). Also, you claim you have solved the first part; but if you inspect the results, you will find you have not (the result is incorrect).

Comment: @Amadan yes, first option must be the original array without any addition. I am executing it with node, so now I am running the code in terminal.

Comment: @briosheje yes, it implies all the possible combinations.

Comment: I have edited the code, but it is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it using recursive functions.
In code below there are 3 simple function,

`arsum(ar1,ar2)` calculates sum of two array `ar1` & `ar2`

`getArr(n,i)` returns an array of size `n` which all of its elements are zero except the one in place `i` (that's `1`)

`iterateNBlock(inArray, block)` is the start point

`calculate(arrayOfArray, block)` is the recursive function. when `block===0` the input array is result.

in your example when block is 1, you calculate some arrays as result, and when block is 2 you do to all of these arrays, what you did to the first array.

so for `block=n` you do the same things to the results of when `block=n-1`.

```
function arsum(ar1, ar2){
    let sum = [];
    for(let i=0; i<ar1.length; i++){
        sum.push(ar1[i]+ar2[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
function getArr(n,i){
    let ar = new Array(n).fill(0);
    if(i>=0 && i<ar.length)
        ar[i]=1;
    return ar;
}
function calculate(arrayOfArray, block){
    if(block===0)return arrayOfArray;

    let n = arrayOfArray[0].length;
    let next = [];

    for(let i=-1; i<n; i++){
        let ar = getArr(n, i);
        for(let j=0 ; j<arrayOfArray.length; j++){
            next.push(arsum(arrayOfArray[j], ar));
        }
    }
    return calculate(next, block-1);
}
function iterateNBlock(inArray, block){
    return calculate([inArray], block);
}
```

It was a little hard for me to explain it, hope to help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest to your code that I could make it. `iterateOneBlock` is basically your function. The first line adds the copy (by `Array.from`) of the `in_array` (the case of adding `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`).  Similarly, inside the loop we must copy `in_array` again, to avoid adding the reference to the same array over and over. The next function encodes the intuition that each added block is basically multiplying the number of entries in the result: if you start with 1, for one block (assuming length of 5) you have 6 entries; add another block, and you get 6 entries for each existing entry; and so on. The last function is just a wrapper, because the workhorse function needs an array of arrays, but we receive just an array.

```js
function iterateOneBlock(in_array) {
  let out_array = [Array.from(in_array)];
  for (let i = 0; i < in_array.length; i++) {
    let tmp_array = Array.from(in_array);
    tmp_array[i] += 1;
    out_array.push(tmp_array);
  }
  return out_array;
}
function iterateMultipleBlocksOnArrayOfArrays(in_array_array, blocks) {
  let tmp_array_array = [];
  for (let n = 0; n < blocks; n++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < in_array_array.length; i++) {
      tmp_array_array.push(...iterateOneBlock(in_array_array[i]));
    }
    in_array_array = tmp_array_array;
    tmp_array_array = [];
  }
  return in_array_array;
}
function iterateMultipleBlocks(in_array, blocks) {
  return iterateMultipleBlocksOnArrayOfArrays([in_array], blocks);
}
console.log(iterateMultipleBlocks([0, 0, 0], 2))
```